# Filtered NSArray not working right when a ? is in the NSString

Tags: ios, nsarray

When I try to filter an array of strings I do not get a match for the value that has a ? in it when using filteredArrayUsingPredicate:.  You can substitute the URLs for just a sentence with a ? and you still get the same thing.

Here's the simplified code:

```
-(void)test {

    NSArray *theURLs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://www.google.com", @"http://www.google.com?test=1", nil];

    NSString *currentURL = @"http://www.google.com?test=1";
    NSLog(@"currentURL %@", currentURL);
    NSPredicate *matchURLPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES[cd] %@", [currentURL lowercaseString]];
    NSLog(@"match predicate %@", matchURLPredicate);
    NSArray *filteredArray = [theURLs filteredArrayUsingPredicate:matchURLPredicate];
    NSLog(@"filtered array %@", filteredArray);
    if ([filteredArray count]== 0) {

        NSLog(@"http://www.google.com?test=1 should have been found, but  was not");

    } else {

        NSLog(@"http://www.google.com?test=1 was found");

    }

}
```

If I look for just @"http://www.google.com" it is filtered just fine.

Here's the corrected code:

```
-(void)test {

    NSArray *theURLs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://www.google.com", @"http://www.google.com?test=1", nil];

    NSString *currentURL = @"http://www.google.com\\?test=1";
    NSLog(@"currentURL %@", currentURL);
    NSPredicate *matchURLPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES[cd] %@", [currentURL lowercaseString]];
    NSLog(@"match predicate %@", matchURLPredicate);
    NSArray *filteredArray = [theURLs filteredArrayUsingPredicate:matchURLPredicate];
    NSLog(@"filtered array %@", filteredArray);
    if ([filteredArray count]== 0) {

        NSLog(@"http://www.google.com?test=1 should have been found, but  was not");

    } else {

        NSLog(@"http://www.google.com?test=1 was found");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `?` might be a special character. just escape it:

```
@"http://www.google.com\\?test=1"
```

Comment: Thanks, I had tried a single escape, but didn't realize that two would be needed.

Comment: @Chad: two are needed because one is eaten by the string literal.